# How to extract multiple table from HTML in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all data of security bulletin table from html *https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/dreamweaver/apsb21-13.html*. Based on my code, I only can extract the data in the table one by one. The code cannot extract the overall data from the table.

This is my code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
gdp = soup.find_all("table")

table = gdp[0]
body = table.find_all("tr")
head = body[0]
body_rows = body[1:] 

headings = []
for item in head.find_all("td"): 
    item = (item.text).rstrip("\n")
    headings.append(item)

all_rows = [] # will be a list for list for all rows
for row_num in range(len(body_rows)): # A row at a time
    row = [] # this will old entries for one row
    for row_item in body_rows[row_num].find_all("td"): 
        aa = re.sub("(\xa0)|(\n)|,","",row_item.text)
        row.append(aa)
    all_rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=all_rows,columns=headings)
df.head()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=all_rows,columns=headings)
df.to_csv('C:/Users//AdobeAir-APSB16-23 Security Update Available for Adobe AIR.csv')
df.head()
```

The output of the code is

```
Bulletin ID Date Published  Priority
0   APSB21-13   February 09 2021    3
```

For this code, I imported library such as Beautifulsoup, requests, pandas and re. Hope anyone can help me on how to extract the data in the table all at once and can be converted into csv format. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `pandas` do the heavy-lifting for you with `read_html`:

```
url = 'https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/dreamweaver/apsb21-13.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
dfs[1]
```

Output:

```
             Product  Affected Versions           Platform
0  Adobe Dreamweaver               20.2  Windows and macOS
1  Adobe Dreamweaver               21.0  Windows and macOS
```

P.S. It outputs a list of all tables found in the HTML. For example, `dfs[0]` is the first table:

```
  Bulletin ID     Date Published  Priority
0   APSB21-13  February 09, 2021         3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Nice! The code is more simple than before. I wanted to extract the data from the tables in one csv file. So, I add on some more code in order for me to see the overall data from the tables.

```pd.concat([df[0], df[1], df[2], df[3]], ignore_index=True).to_csv('C:/Users/MY-PC/test.csv')```

Comment: The output

```Bulletin ID Date Published Priority Product Affected Versions Platform Updated Version Priority rating Vulnerability Category Vulnerability Impact Severity CVE Numbers
0 APSB21-13 February 09, 2021 3         
1    Adobe Dreamweaver 20.2 Windows and macOS      
2    Adobe Dreamweaver 21 Windows and macOS      
3    Adobe Dreamweaver  Windowsâ€¯and macOS 20.2.1 3    
4    Adobe Dreamweaver  Windowsâ€¯and macOS 21.1 3    
5         Uncontrolled Search Path Element Information disclosure Important CVE-2021-21055```


Hope it is useful for others too.